# Hibernate being slow to fetch data from view but the same request is instant in sql

Tags: spring, hibernate

I tried everything , I have an SQL view with 700k lines, the query should result in a dozen lines.
When hibernate do the request it takes 1 minute, when I literraly copy paste the hibernate request from the log and launch it from Microsoft SQL server management studio (replacing the "?" with the value) I get instant results.

here is my map class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vw_my_view")
@Getter
@Setter
@IdClass(AgreggateKey.class)
public class RecordsData implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Type")
    private String type;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "value")
    private Long value;

...
(more attributes)
...

    static public class AgreggateKey implements Serializable {

        protected String type;
        protected Long id;

        public AgreggateKey() {
        }

        public AgreggateKey(String type, Long id) {
            this.type= type;
            this.id= id;
        }
    }
```

the AgreggateKey was needed because no column was single handedly unique, but type + id is unique.

here is my repo :

```
@Repository
public interface RecordsDataRepository extends JpaRepository<RecordsData, Long> {

    List<RecordsData> findByIdAndType(Long id, String type);

    List<RecordsData> findById(Long id);

}
```

when I call `recordsDataRepository.findById(id)` (or findByIdAndType) it takes almost a minute.

what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say, but it's best to ask your DBA about this. Maybe you are missing an index? If you execute the query again after Hibernate has executed it once, you already warmed up various caches, so the second execution usually is faster. The optimizer of a database is very dependent on statistics and if you replace a parameter marker with a concrete value, the optimizer can use different statistics (value distribution, selectivity, etc.). This can have a big impact on the query execution plan. This can be a reason for choosing an IndexScan vs. FullTableScan.

Comment: sending multiple time the same request is always slow with hibernate, and always fast on SSMS. For now my workaround has been to send the full request in native that used to be the view job, and request directly the tables behind, but I'd prefer a real solution.

Comment: Well, to me this sounds like you are not executing the exact same query as Hibernate. Can you show your two ways of querying? There is some overhead in the marshalling process i.e. creating the entity objects, but that is usually rather low. You have to understand that Hibernate fetches the whole result immediately when you run the query to materialize objects, whereas JDBC has a `ResultSet` that fetches data in batches only when you request it. Be sure to measure the time when you fetch all data from the `ResultSet`.